# How can I recover my Mac when I leave the focus within a VM?

Tags: windows, macos, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have had this happen a few times.

I am using a Windows VM on my Mac, I am working within my Windows Vm (via VirtualBox, fullscreen), leave it for a few hours, come back, and then my Mac is essentially bricked until I restart it, as the Windows VM has gone to sleep.

I know that I can change the settings on the Windows instance to not go to sleep, but in this scenario is there anything I can do on the Mac to jump out of the VirtualBox session?

Thanks

Comment: Iirc you configure a key to go back to host. I'm windows host is right ctrl. Perhaps is right cmd in mac?